# Weak solution $-u''+u=H$ on $(-1,1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'm given the equation following equation for $x \in (0,1)$:

\begin{align}
-u''(x)+u(x)=H(x) \\
u'(-1)=u'(1)=0
\end{align}
where $H(x)=0$ on $(-1,0)$ and $H(x)=1$ on $[0,1)$.

Now I first need to show that there exists a unique weak solution to this problem and then compute the solution.
For the first part I did the following:
By multiplying with a test function $v$, partial integration and using the boundary conditions I can rewrite the problem to
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 u'v' +uv dx = \int_{-1}^1 Hv dx= \int_0^1 v dx.
\end{align}
I define the first part as  a bilinear form $a(u,v)$ and the second part as linear functional $f(v)$. Therefore, the problem is reduced to finding a $u \in H^1(0,1)$ such that for all $v \in H^1(0,1)$ it holds that
\begin{align}
a(u,v))=f(v)
\end{align}
To use Lax-Milgram I showed that $f$ is bounded and $a$ is bounded and coercive:
\begin{align}
|a(u,v)|\leq ||u'||_{L^2} ||v'||_{L^2} +||u||_{L^2} ||u||_{L^2} \leq 2||u||_{H^1} ||v||_{H^1} \\
a(u,u)=||u||^2_{L^2} \\
|f(v)|\leq \int_{-1}^1|v(x)|dx \leq ||v||_{L^2} \leq ||v||_{H^1}
\end{align}
Hence, by Lax-Milgram, I've shown that there exists a unique weak solution.

I'm struggling with the second part of the question which asks to compute the weak solution. I guessed that the solution could be $u=H$ and tried to verify it:

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 H(x)v'(x)+\int_{-1}^1 H(x)v(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1 \delta_0(x)v'(x)+\int_0^1 v(x)dx \stackrel{!}{=}\int_0^1 v(x)dx 
\end{align}

For the last equality to be true I'd need that $\int_{-1}^1 \delta_0 v'(x)=0$. I doubt that this is true, though I'm not sure.
(I know that $\int_{-{\infty}}^{\infty} \delta_0 v'(x)=v'(0)$).
Is my approach correct or is the solution completely different?

Comment: Your definition of $H$ does not even make sense. How can it be $0$ on $(-1, 1)$ and $1$ on $[0, 1)$?

Comment: You should keep in mind that the Heaviside function does not belong to $H^1$, the space where you have proven existence and uniqueness of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look to the EDO separately on $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, while fixing the additional condition $u(0)= c$, we get the following differential equations
$$
\begin{cases}
-u'' + u = 0\\ u'(-1)=0, u(0)= c
\end{cases}\qquad
\begin{cases}
-u'' + u = 1\\ u(0)=c, u'(1)= 0
\end{cases}
$$

If we choose $c = \frac 12$, the concatenation of the two solutions is defined and is $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
u(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{e^{-x}+e^{x+2}}{2+2 e^2}, & x \leq 0\\[1em]
-\dfrac{e^{2-x}+e^x-2-2 e^2}{2 \left(1+e^2\right)}, & x >0
\end{cases}
$$

Questions you should consider:

1. Is this your weak solution?
2. What if we choose other values for $u(0)$? Do we still get a weak solution to the original problem?
3. Does this contradict the uniqueness result?

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I still struggle to answer the questions you stated. After some calculations I believe that the $u(x)$ you computed  is indeed a weak solution (and I think it remains a weak solution if we change $c$. So why does this NOT contradict the uniqueness result? All the solutions are in $H^1$ aren't they?